# Check size of object when read from file

Tags: r

Is there a way of checking the size of a file which has been read in? I am specifically trying to figure out the in-memory size of a shapefile read in by the `maptools` library:

```
df = readShapeSpatial("/path/file.shp")
```

Comment: If you want the size of df you are not actually "checking the file size", so your title and first sentence don't make sense.  Use file.info() for file size on disk.

Comment: @mdsumner -- Agreed. A while back, I edited the title to read "Check object size", since calling the size of R objects "file size" will be misleading to (nearly) anybody looking at the post, but the OP rolled back the change. Not sure why, but you may be correct that they really do want `file.info("/path/file.shp")$size`, in which case `object.size(df)` isn't giving them what they think it is.

Comment: It's pretty common with shapefiles and some other GIS data that folks don't distinguish between them (files vs. objects) since many software products don't either (which can be good or bad, but often technically incorrect at least).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
object.size(df) ..................................
```

Answer (score 6):

See `?object.size`:

```
a <- runif(1e6)
object.size(a)
print(object.size(a), units="Mb")
```